# Trying to launch a new FXML file in javaFX using a method call

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to call another fxml page using a method but getting the error below.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread;
>   currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0  at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236) at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
>     at javafx.stage.Stage.(Stage.java:241)    at
>   javafx.stage.Stage.(Stage.java:227)     at
>   thebio.MainController.StudentRegistration(MainController.java:134)

The method below is the one i used in carrying out this event, i don't know where i am getting it wrong please, and any assistance will definitely be well appreciated.

```
public void StudentRegistration(){
    try {   
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        Parent root1;
        root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Student.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("ABC");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
        stage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Platform#runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) to update the **GUI** from a **non-GUI** thread.

```
Platform.runLater(()->{
    Parent root1;
    root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Student.fxml"));
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("ABC");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
    stage.show();
});
```

Comment: thanks for that, i do appreciate.i am new to javafx, i don't know how i am going to implement that please.

i sincerely do appreciate your fast resposne.

Comment: what if i want to close the previous fxml, how will i do that pls?

Comment: @DerinS can't say without looking at the code, but you can't close the window from this class, if you don't have a reference to the stage Object. If you have, just call `.hide()` on it